# Credentials manager for Azure Data Factory not working

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

[image]

Good day!

I am working on moving files via Azure Data Factory from on-prem file store and/or ftp site to Azure Blob storage using Copy Data activity. When setting security access, I am using credential manager. However, when clicking 'Set credential' a string 'Preparing...' shows for a split moment, and then nothing happens and box is left blank. What is exactly credentials manager? Is is a separate application, which needs to be installed or Windows credentials manager available via Administrative tools? I used IE for this. In Chrome it tries to install ClickOnce app, which fails to install with this error log (googling it reveals nothing). Does anyone know the solution?

```
IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity        : CredentialsManager.application, Version=1.1.6273.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c3bce3770c238a49, processorArchitecture=msil

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Online only application.
    * Trust url parameter is set.
ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users\YToropov\Downloads\CredentialsManager.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Deployment and application do not have matching security zones.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [4/5/2017 5:50:08 AM] : Activation of C:\Users\YToropov\Downloads\CredentialsManager.application has started.
    * [4/5/2017 5:50:08 AM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [4/5/2017 5:50:08 AM] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [4/5/2017 5:50:08 AM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (Zone)
        - Deployment and application do not have matching security zones.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: I looked at my data gateway settings and it says 'Data source credential: Credential store: On-premises' instead of Certificate as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-move-data-between-onprem-and-cloud . Could it be a root of the problem?

Comment: This could be why the copy wizard is still in preview.

Comment: @PaulAndrew hehe :)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to clean this folder and try again by using IE11.
C:\Users{account}\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0

if it still not work, you may need to reset the internet options.

Comment: Thanks. I tried and it did not work. I tried doing this even on a new laptop and my experience so far has been that it is completely broken as a feature in Azure. Encrypting credentials does not work from 'Encrypt' button in the Data Factory 'Author and Deploy' either - no Credentials manager app is launched

Comment: I tried... worked for me; however, I created the 'credentials' first using 'credentials tab' within the 'Manage Tab' of ADF (github mode), then assigned it within the configuration of linked service creation... Thanks, Tong Wu

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use the credentials manager, can I suggest you create your data factory in Visual Studio. Then simply deploy it to Azure with different sets of configuration files.

Check out this blog post on how.

https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2017/01/using-azure-data-factory-configuration-files/

This way credentials do not need to be copied into any portal blades and can be handled using other tools. Plus source controlled.

The JSON strings will also be masked if viewed via the Author and Deploy blade.

Plus any changes can be dealt with locally and your on prem linked service in ADF just redeployed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I do use VS15 for creating pipelines after installing ADF templates for VS15 but occasionally use Copy Data (in preview) to create some jsons with all the right options for various activities since there are so many of them and this way I can set the right properties... only to find out that some things are still in development ... Any pointers how to move lots of data from on premises database to Data Lake (in Parquet) for later use w/ Spark? I see data gateway not performing  very well and thinking about having a mirror of on premises database in Azure to use as source

Comment: As a regular thing to upload data or as a one off?

Comment: First full (probably one off) and then incremental updates (regular)

Answer (score 0):

The credential manager is a .NET ClickOnce application running on your OnPrem machine. When using the credential manager to set the username/password, it directly talks to the Gateway so there is no username/password data transfer over the wire. If you use "by web browser" option, the encrypted username/password will be transferred over the wire with a post request and then gets pushed to Gateway. In both options credentials are encrypted, but the Credential Manages saves the roundtrip through public network.

The reason why you get this error is because Chrome by default does not support the .NET ClickOnce application. It should work if you are using IE or Edge.

For this to work on Chrome, you can add an extention to enable ClickOnce application support in Chrome, like the below one

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/meta4-clickonce-launcher/jkncabbipkgbconhaajbapbhokpbgkdc?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but I actually tried IE and it did not work either

Comment: In that case it should be a general Click-Once application issue on IE/Edge. Check the detailed error output when opening with IE (like you showed above) and with some search you should be able to hit a few good docs. If a vanilla machine also has this issue, you may want to double check if there's any domain policy pushed to your machine for Internet Explorer settings.

Answer (score -3):

Solution: Clear the oneClick cache and try to install the application again. Here is the way to clear oneClick cache

From command line run: rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache

If it doesn’t work, delete the real folder:

Windows Vista/7/8/10

C:\users[username]\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\

Windows XP/2003

C:\Documents and Settings\username\LocalSettings\Apps\2.0\

for more information, you can look at this. it may be helpful.
http://codeketchup.blogspot.sg/2013/06/how-to-fix-deployment-and-application.html

======================================================
[security zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlgEe.png)

Comment: Running it manually actually resulted in the error above I posted hence the question.

Comment: are you able to see this pic when clicking the Set Credential ? [ClickOnce Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxvgh.png)

Comment: can you try to reset IE settings ? [How to reset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii5t7.png) and have you seen anything under this path ? "C:\Users\{account}\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0

Comment: Hi, can you check your IE Options ? [Screenshot how to change security zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlgEe.png)  reset all zones to default level and add *.configuration.dataproxy.clouddatahub.net to the trust sites.

Comment: @ Abhishek Narain no