# Data Factory Data Gateway without certificate

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Good day! I started using Azure Data Factory to move some data from on-premises sources to Data Lake for  analysis. When I installed data gateway, I noticed that it uses 'On-premises credentials store' (see picture below) instead of 'Certificate' like most Microsoft documentation shows eg here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-move-data-between-onprem-and-cloud

[image: My setup]

[image: What Microsoft documentation shows]

What am I doing wrong? Is using certificate the 'right' way? How do I add  certificate to my gateway then?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The above screenshots holds good for Gateways created before October 2016. This certificate was used to encrypt the on premise data store credentials before storing the encrypted credentials on Cloud.

Post [October 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-gateway-release-notes#2461511), the Gateways do not let user provide certificate for credential encryption as Gateways now leverage [DPAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx) for securing it and stores it locally on the Gateway machine. 
So now there is only 1 certificate required by Gateway, which is used for securing endpoints (port 8050) for click-once based credential manager application for on premise Data Store credential setting.

Thanks for asking this question, we are in process of updating the documents.

Let me know if you have any other question.

Comment: Thanks, Abishek, for clarifying it. Do you have any info on the original related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234584/credentials-manager-for-azure-data-factory-not-working/ ? I would appreciate if you could help.

Comment: let me check that out.